# Python string formatting within list

Tags: python, string, list

What is best way to achieve the following? Each of the elements in the list needs to be appended with a common string.

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'configs'))

files = ['%s/file1', '%s/file2'] % path
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply it to each format in turn:

```
files = ['%s/file1' % path, '%s/file2' % path]
```

However, you should really use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) here; then the correct platform-specific directory separator will be used, always:

```
files = [os.path.join(path, 'file1'), os.path.join(path, 'file2')]
```

If this is getting repetitive, use a list comprehension:

```
files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in ('file1', 'file2')]
```